# How can I get rid of deprecated methods?

Tags: android, notifications, deprecated

I am unable to change deprecation from the methods below I am using API level 19. Can you please help me out with this issue?

```
Notification notification = new Notification(icon, message, when);
 ......
notification.setLatestEventInfo(context, title, subTitle, intent);
```

Actually I tried Notification.Builder but not getting proper output can you guys show how to use Notification.Builder for above 2 statements. Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

From http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Notification.html:

*This method was deprecated in API level 11. Use [Notification.Builder](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Notification.Builder.html) instead.*

Comment: yeah thanks for reply.. but by using notification builder I am getting errors ....what I should do?